# Spring doesn't assign authorities to OAuth2 User

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In my Spring Boot app I have OAuth2Login implemented, but when I log in with OAuth2 using Google, Spring doesn't assign the authorities I've specified. First here is my UserDetailsManager

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager = 
        new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
    jdbcUserDetailsManager.setUsersByUsernameQuery(
            "select username, password, enabled from accounts where username=?");
    jdbcUserDetailsManager.setAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery(
        "select username, authority from authorities where username=?");
    return jdbcUserDetailsManager;
}
```

Here is my oauth2 configuration

```
.oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
    .loginPage("/my-login")
    .userInfoEndpoint(userInfoEndpointConfig ->
        userInfoEndpointConfig
            .userService(oauthUserService))
    .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
        CustomOAuth2User oauthUser = 
            (CustomOAuth2User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        accountService.processOAuthPostLogin(
            oauthUser.getUsername(), oauthUser.getEmail());
        response.sendRedirect("/home");
    })
```

The oauthUserService has 1 method "loadUser".

```
@Override
public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
    OAuth2User user = super.loadUser(userRequest);
    return new CustomOAuth2User(user);
}
```

The CustomOAuth2User

```
public class CustomOAuth2User implements OAuth2User, Serializable {
private OAuth2User oauth2User;

public CustomOAuth2User(OAuth2User oauth2User) {
    this.oauth2User = oauth2User;
}

@Override
public Map<String, Object> getAttributes() {
    return oauth2User.getAttributes();
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return oauth2User.getAuthorities();
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return oauth2User.getAttribute("name");
}

public String getUsername() {
    return oauth2User.getAttribute("name");
}
```

The accountService.proccessOAuthPostLogin

```
@Transactional
public void processOAuthPostLogin(String username, String email) {
    Account account = accountDAO.findByUsername(username);
    if (account != null) {
        return;
    }

    jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO accounts (username, enabled, email, provider) "
            + "VALUES (?,?,?,?)", username, true, email, "GOOGLE");
    jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO authorities VALUES (?,?)",
        username, "ROLE_CLIENT");
}
```

Spring doesn't assign "ROLE_CLIENT" to the OAuth User, how can I assign authorities to OAuth User?